# Selecting data in MS Access with vb.net is very slow. Am I doing it right?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm currently working on a program for work that uses data in a very weirdly organized MS Access database.

I have to jump from tables to tables to get the information I need.

Now I'm selecting less than 200 x 100 data but it seems like it takes a lot of time to perform all the querys. It takes about 150 seconds.

I have no real background in databases exept for the couple websites I coded in php and mySql so I was wondering if you guys could take a quick look at my code and tell me if the structure and the emplacements of the querys is correct or if it's what makes it so slow.

```
Dim connectionStr = Constants.Input.MDB.CONNECTION_STRING & _
        "Data Source=" & dbFullPath & ";"

    Dim connection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionStr)

    connection.Open()

    Dim query = "SELECT " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.CYCLE_ID & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.COMMAND_ID & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.QUANTITY & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.FINAL_TEMP & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.DATE_TIME & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.DRY_MALAX_TIME & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.TOTAL_MALAX_TIME & _
                " FROM " & Constants.Input.MDB.Tables.CYCLE & _
                " WHERE " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.DATE_TIME & _
                " BETWEEN #" & startDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") & "# AND #" & endDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") & "#"

    Dim dbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection)

    ' Table readers
    Dim reader_cycle = dbCommand.ExecuteReader

    Dim reader_command As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    Dim reader_strCache As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    Dim reader_recipe As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    Dim reader_coldFeedsRecipeDetails As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    Dim reader_materials As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    Dim reader_cycleDetails As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    Dim reader_location As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    ' Cycle table
    While (reader_cycle.Read)

        Dim row(nbCols) As String

        row(Constants.Input.MDB.CYCLE_ID_COLUMN_INDEX) = reader_cycle.Item(0)
        row(Constants.Input.MDB.COMMAND_ID_COLUMN_INDEX) = reader_cycle.Item(1)
        row(Constants.Input.MDB.TOTAL_QTY_COLUMN_INDEX) = reader_cycle.Item(2)
        row(Constants.Input.MDB.FINAL_TEMP_COLUMN_INDEX) = reader_cycle.Item(3)
        Dim date_time = CStr(reader_cycle.Item(4)).Split(" "c)
        row(Constants.Input.MDB.DATE_COLUMN_INDEX) = date_time(0)
        row(Constants.Input.MDB.TIME_COLUMN_INDEX) = date_time(1)
        row(Constants.Input.MDB.TOTAL_MALAX_TIME_COLUMN_INDEX) = reader_cycle.Item(5)
        row(Constants.Input.MDB.DRY_MALAX_TIME_COLUMN_INDEX) = reader_cycle.Item(6)

        query = "SELECT " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.FORMULA_NAME_ID & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.TRUCK_ID & _
                " FROM " & Constants.Input.MDB.Tables.COMMAND & _
                " WHERE " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.COMMAND_ID & " " & _
                " = " & row(Constants.Input.MDB.COMMAND_ID_COLUMN_INDEX)

        dbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection)

        reader_command = dbCommand.ExecuteReader

        Dim recipeNameID As String

        ' Command table
        While (reader_command.Read)

            recipeNameID = reader_command.Item(0)
            row(Constants.Input.MDB.TRUCK_ID_COLUMN_INDEX) = reader_command.Item(1)

        End While ' End Command Table

        reader_command.Close()

        query = "SELECT " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.STRING_CONTENT & _
                            " FROM " & Constants.Input.MDB.Tables.STRING_CACHE & _
                            " WHERE " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.STRING_ID & _
                            " = " & recipeNameID

        dbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection)

        reader_strCache = dbCommand.ExecuteReader

        ' String Cache (formula name)
        While (reader_strCache.Read)

            row(Constants.Input.MDB.RECIPE_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX) = reader_strCache.Item(0)

        End While ' End String Cache

        reader_strCache.Close()

        query = "SELECT " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.RECIPE_DESC & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.QUANTITY & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.COLD_FEEDS_RECIPE_ID & _
                " FROM " & Constants.Input.MDB.Tables.RECIPES & _
                " WHERE " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.RECIPE_NAME & _
                " = " & "'" & row(Constants.Input.MDB.RECIPE_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX) & "'"

        dbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection)

        reader_recipe = dbCommand.ExecuteReader

        Dim coldFeedRecipeID As Object

        ' Recipe
        While (reader_recipe.Read)

            row(Constants.Input.MDB.RECIPE_DESC_COLUMN_INDEX) = reader_recipe.Item(0)
            row(Constants.Input.MDB.RECIPE_QTY_COLUMN_INDEX) = reader_recipe.Item(1)
            coldFeedRecipeID = reader_recipe.Item(2)

        End While ' End Recipe

        reader_recipe.Close()

        If (Not IsDBNull(coldFeedRecipeID)) Then


            query = "SELECT " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.MATERIAL_ID & ", " & _
                                Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.MATERIAL_PERCENTAGE & _
                    " FROM " & Constants.Input.MDB.Tables.COLD_FEEDS_RECIPES_DETAILS & _
                    " WHERE " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.CFRD_TABLE_RECIPE_ID & _
                    " = " & coldFeedRecipeID

            dbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection)

            reader_coldFeedsRecipeDetails = dbCommand.ExecuteReader


            ' Cold Feeds Recipe Details
            While (reader_coldFeedsRecipeDetails.Read)

                query = "SELECT " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.LOCATION_NAME & _
                    " FROM " & Constants.Input.MDB.Tables.LOCATION & _
                    " WHERE " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.MATERIAL_ID & _
                    " = " & reader_coldFeedsRecipeDetails.Item(0)

                dbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection)

                reader_location = dbCommand.ExecuteReader

                Dim locationName As String

                ' Location
                If (reader_location.Read) Then

                    locationName = reader_location.Item(0)
                Else
                    locationName = Constants.Input.MDB.DEFAULT_LOCATION

                End If ' End Location

                Dim locationIndex = Constants.Input.MDB.getColumnIndex(locationName)

                row(locationIndex + Constants.Input.MDB.LOCATION_ROW_INDEX) = locationName

                reader_location.Close()

                query = "SELECT " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.MATERIAL_NAME & _
                        " FROM " & Constants.Input.MDB.Tables.MATERIALS & _
                        " WHERE " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.MATERIAL_ID & _
                        " = " & reader_coldFeedsRecipeDetails.Item(0)

                dbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection)

                reader_materials = dbCommand.ExecuteReader

                ' Materials
                While (reader_materials.Read)

                    row(locationIndex + Constants.Input.MDB.MATERIAL_NAME_ROW_INDEX) = reader_materials.Item(0)
                    row(locationIndex + Constants.Input.MDB.PERCENTAGE_ROW_INDEX) = reader_coldFeedsRecipeDetails.Item(1)

                End While ' End materials

                reader_materials.Close()

            End While ' End Cold Feeds ...

            reader_coldFeedsRecipeDetails.Close()

        End If

        query = "SELECT " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.MATERIAL_NAME_ID & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.FORMULA_QUANTITY & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.DOSAGE_QUANTITY & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.REAL_QUANTITY & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.LOCATION & ", " & _
                            Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.MANUEL_MODE & _
                " FROM " & Constants.Input.MDB.Tables.CYCLE_DETAILS & _
                " WHERE " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.CYCLE_ID & _
                " = " & row(Constants.Input.MDB.CYCLE_ID_COLUMN_INDEX)

        dbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection)

        reader_cycleDetails = dbCommand.ExecuteReader

        ' Cycle details
        While (reader_cycleDetails.Read)

            Dim materialNameID = reader_cycleDetails.Item(0)

            Dim location = reader_cycleDetails.Item(4)

            query = "SELECT " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.LOCATION_NAME & _
                    " FROM " & Constants.Input.MDB.Tables.LOCATION & _
                    " WHERE " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.LOCATION_ID & _
                    " = " & location

            dbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection)

            reader_location = dbCommand.ExecuteReader

            Dim locationName As String

            ' Location
            While (reader_location.Read)

                locationName = reader_location.Item(0)

            End While ' End Location

            Dim locationIndex = Constants.Input.MDB.getColumnIndex(locationName)

            row(locationIndex + Constants.Input.MDB.LOCATION_ROW_INDEX) = locationName

            reader_location.Close()

            query = "SELECT " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.STRING_CONTENT & _
                    " FROM " & Constants.Input.MDB.Tables.STRING_CACHE & _
                    " WHERE " & Constants.Input.MDB.Columns.STRING_ID & _
                    " = " & materialNameID

            dbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection)

            reader_strCache = dbCommand.ExecuteReader

            ' String Cache (formula name)
            While (reader_strCache.Read)

                row(locationIndex + Constants.Input.MDB.MATERIAL_NAME_ROW_INDEX) = reader_strCache.Item(0)

            End While ' End String Cache

            reader_strCache.Close()

            row(locationIndex + Constants.Input.MDB.RECIPE_QTY_ROW_INDEX) = reader_cycleDetails.Item(1)
            row(locationIndex + Constants.Input.MDB.DOSAGE_QTY_ROW_INDEX) = reader_cycleDetails.Item(2)
            row(locationIndex + Constants.Input.MDB.REAL_QTY_ROW_INDEX) = reader_cycleDetails.Item(3)
            row(locationIndex + Constants.Input.MDB.MANUAL_ROW_INDEX) = reader_cycleDetails.Item(5)

        End While ' End cycle details

        reader_cycleDetails.Close()

        rowList.AddLast(row)

    End While ' End Cycle

    reader_cycle.Close()

    connection.Close()

    Return rowList
```

Comment: It looks to me like you need to learn how to use JOINs.  Your life would get infinitely easier.  Make use of the Query Designer; you can join together tables graphically, and see the output of your efforts interactively.  You can go to SQL View to see the SQL that the designer has generated.

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm!
It went from taking 150 seconds to 1.5 second for the same task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing many many different selects against the database.  Each time you open and close a connection there is a large IO cost in addition to the cost of the actual query.

As @RobertHarvey mentioned, you need to learn to use JOINs.