# How to use 2 connection objects while importing data from one database to another in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am using the following code to select from one database and need to insert into another database.. Please suggest me the code:

Code :

```
'Connection for Original database from where i have to import

Dim constrOrg As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strPath
Dim conn_OrgDB As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(constrOrg)

'Connection for my database to where i have to import

Dim App_Path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()
Dim constr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + App_Path + "Mydb.accdb"

Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(constr)

    Dim strSelInv_one As String = ("SELECT * FROM INV_ONE where (DOCU_DT>=@stdt AND DOCU<=@enddt) ")
    Dim comm_inv_one As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelInv_one, conn_OrgDB )

    comm_inv_one.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stdt", StTime)
    comm_inv_one.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddt", Endtime)

    dr = comm_inv_one.ExecuteReader

    Do While dr.Read = True

    Dim strInsInv1 As String = "INSERT INTO INVOICE_ONE(CODE_NO,LAY,..) SELECT CODE_NO,LAY,... FROM INV_ONE where (CODE_NO=@code)"
        Dim comm_Insinv1 As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strInsInv1, cnnOLEDB)

        comm_Insinv1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", Code_no)
       comm_Insinv1.ExecuteNonQuery()

      Loop


       'Here INVOICE_ONE table belongs cnnOLEDB connection obj of one database and INV_ONE table belongs to conn_OrgDB  connection object of another database..


    ' How to use the 2 connection object ? If i use only one connection object i.e. cnnOLEDB it gives the following Error:

    " The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'INV_ONE'.  Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.     "
```

Please suggest me the code..
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code, obviously don't make it as long as his ( basically wack out stuff you don't need and imput your code, now ....

in addition to :

```
Dim connectionStr = Constants.Input.MDB.CONNECTION_STRING & _
    "Data Source=" & dbFullPath & ";"
Dim connection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionStr)
```

in addition use

```
Dim connectionStr2 = "Other conection string"
Dim connection2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionStr)
```

and import it into his code.

link:
[Selecting data in MS Access with vb.net is very slow. Am I doing it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489815/selecting-data-in-ms-access-with-vb-net-is-very-slow-am-i-doing-it-right)

I am sorry if this won't help, since i don't have an access db i cannot further test this.
Reguards.

Comment: Hi...I have tried with that..i.e. using 2nd connection object but it gives the following error "The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'INV_ONE'.  Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly." I have edited my question please check it

Comment: Then my solution for you is to simply instantiate a 2nd object for this.

This is how i do it ( Yeah its SQL but should be modifiable )

Comment: sorry.. i didn't get any thing....actually i am very new to vb.net and using back end as ms-access.. so can you please solve my problem using my code... thank you..

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be use to Access to create Linked Tables in the target database that point to the corresponding tables in the source (production) database. Then you can at least manipulate both sets of tables using the same connection, thereby giving you the option of doing

```
INSERT INTO INVOICE_1 (codeno, lchlndt, ...)
SELECT codeno, lchlndt, ... FROM INV_ONE ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Gord, I was doing the same but the client don't want like that as they may change the path of original database... and if they change the path of original database then it may cause problem as both the databases are linked.... that's why i want to import the data periodically.... Thanks again..

Comment: I have edited my question . Please check it and help me with that code... thank you